# Работа со строками и String.format

Tags: java

Мне нужно подставлять динамически значение `symbol` в следующий код:

```
String.format("UPPER(abonent_base.id::text) LIKE \'%s%\'", symbol);
```

Как подправить его, чтобы заработало без ошибок?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знак процента указывается в строке формата как `%%`

```
String.format("UPPER(abonent_base.id::text) LIKE \'%s%%\'", symbol);
```